# defining http as DI gives EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use `private http: Http` and it gives me 
`error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error`

I'm using `http` in my component

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable,Subscription} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { NouiFormatter } from 'ng2-nouislider';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-char-maker',
  templateUrl: './char-maker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./char-maker.component.css']
})
export class CharMakerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private http: Http)
  { 
    var obj;
  }
  ngOnInit() {

}
}
```

If I comment `private http: Http` in constructor the error goes away.
What I'm missing here?

Comment: have you imported the http module ?

Comment: You must have forgot to add HttpModule in your app.module.ts file.

Comment: show your app.module.ts

Comment: Its confusing at the start, but very simple later. First you must import the module (HttpModule in this case) and later you can import its classes (Http in this case) in your components. Also you might just add Http as providers in your main module, but that is not recommended (because of other dependencies). So in your app.module.ts add `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'`, then add `HttpModule` to the array of imports.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, I forgot to import `HttpModule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Angular v[4.3](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/07/angular-43-now-available.html)**

You can use the `HttpClientModule`. Import it from

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

and add this to your imports

```
 imports: [
 HttpClientModule,
  //... more code
  ]
```

**For < v4.3**

You can just use the `HttpModule` and import it from

```
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http'
```

and add it to your imports

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **`HttpModule`** under imports,

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       HttpModule
]
```